# $X$ compact Hausdorff implies $x\mapsto \mathfrak{m}_x$ is a homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space. Denote by $\mathfrak m_x$ the prime ideal of $C(X)$ comprised of functions vanishing at $x$. Topologize $\operatorname{MaxSpec}C(X)$ with the initial topology from $X$. I want to prove the map $x\mapsto \mathfrak m_x$ is a homeomorphism. I know it's bijective. Its inverse is continuous as a map $\operatorname{MaxSpec}C(X)\rightarrow X$, but why is it the assignment $x\mapsto \mathfrak m_x$ continuous?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but if you know that $f:\operatorname{MaxSpec} C(X)\rightarrow X$ is bijective and you put the initial topology, so that the open sets are exactly the sets of the form $f^{-1}(U)$, well you just put the corresponding topology on $\operatorname{MaxSpec} $. I mean, it is a homeomorphism by construction.

Comment: Mmh, I just saw from the link below that you meant the initial topology from $C(X)$, that is the topology generated by the sets $f^{-1}(\varphi^{-1}(U))$ for all $\varphi:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and all open set $U\subset \mathbb{R}$. Because $f^{-1}$ is bijective, you only need to show that $X$ is endowed with the initial topology from $C(X)$. This is exactly what is done in the link.

Comment: @Roland so they're homeomorphic because they're in bijection and both have the initial topology from $C(X)$?

Comment: In short, yes. There is something to prove, namely that $X$ has the initial topology from $C(X)$. Now if $X\simeq Y$ is a bijection between two sets, $A=\{Y\rightarrow Z_i\}$ a set of maps from $Y$ and $B=\{X\rightarrow Z_i\}$ the corresponding set of maps from $X$, and if $Y$ and $X$ are endowed with the initial topology from $A$ and $B$, then obviously, $X\simeq Y$ is also an homeomorphism. This is exactly what is happening here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its inverse is continuous and closed i.e it sends closed to closed hence it sends open to open (it is bijective). This mean that your map is continuous.

Closed because the two spaces are compacts, and a closed subset is compact, so its image is compact, in particular closed (Hausdorff).

Comment: How do you know $\operatorname{MaxSpec}C(X)$ is compact? Also, could you explain the proof [here](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2009/11/24/spectra-of-rings-of-continuous-functions/)?

Comment: If $V_i=f^{-1}(U_i) $ is an open cover of this space then $U_i $ is an open cover of $X $ wich is compact, hence we can exatract a finie cover